# Auto download CSV file after link is clicked

Tags: php, csv

I am using PHP to create csvs files, put them into a folder and then zip the folder. This all works perfectly however I can't then get the ZIP the user created to auto download.

EDIT

it now works after taking out a redirect, however it lacks the .zip extension when being downloading, is there a way to force this?

My zips are stored in /zips in the root

Here is my code

```
 // Add the folder we just created to a zip file.
$zip_name = 'groups_' . time();
$zip_directory = '/zips';
$zip = new zip( $zip_name, $zip_directory );
$zip->add_directory( 'group-csvs' );
$zip->save();

$zip_path = $zip->get_zip_path();

header( "Content-Description: File Transfer" );
header( "Content-type: application/zip" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $zip_name . "");
header( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $zip_path ) );

readfile($zip_path);
```

Here is the get path method and constructor in my zip class

```
   public function __construct( $file_name, $zip_directory)
   {
        $this->zip = new ZipArchive();
        $this->path = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $zip_directory . $file_name . '.zip';
        $this->zip->open( $this->path, ZipArchive::CREATE );
    }

   /**
     * Get the absolute path to the zip file
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_zip_path()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
```

I don't get any errors, it just creates the zip then nothing happens

Comment: does your `$zip->save()` calls `close()` of original `ZipArchive` class?

Comment: Yes    public function save()
    {
        $this->zip->close();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Add .zip extension to the name of your file:
`$zip_name = 'groups_' . time() . '.zip';`
The extension you are using in your custom zip class isnt being appended to variable in your main file.